# Webpacker: enable watch mode or unhook webpacker:compile from assets:precompile task in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Rails server running Webpacker compiler under the hood compiles all the files and not just modified files on reload.

I tried enabling the watch mode in `webpacker.yml` under `dev_server` but did not help. So either of these two things I want to do in order to resolve this issue:

1. How to enable the watch mode in Webpacker so that everytime an asset is modified, the only touched asset will be recompiled and hence will fix the reloading to make development a breeze.
2. Since I'm unable to find any solution to the 1st Point, I want to unhook the Webpacker:compile task from assets:precompile. Although I could unhook it on production by disabling the `WEBPACKER_PRECOMPILE` environment variable to `false` and then compiling those assets manually using `./bin/webpack`. However, I'm unable to achieve the result locally when I run

`export WEBPACKER_PRECOMPILE=false && rails s`

To try out the 1st Point, I ran `rails s` in one tab and `./bin/webpack -w` in another. To my surprise, the watch mode with the latter command only compiles the touched file reducing the compilation time to under 1s. However, after reloading the page `rails s` again compiles all the assets which take almost a minute to finish.

Answer (score 1):

While looking at the Webpacker source, this idea struck me:

1. Use `./bin/webpack --watch` command to run Webpack in the watch mode. This will recompile modified files only speeding up the feedback cycle.
2. To unhook the Webpack compilation from the rails server, just set `compile: false` under `development` environment in webpacker.yml